# how to match the following pattern in regex?

Tags: regex, autohotkey

How can I match the the pattern `any number followed by h or t or l` like  `1h , 126h or 1268h` but not  `1.1h 12.6h or 12.68h` in a given paragraph.

I am writing a application that can replace `1h` to `100` or `1268h` to `126800` so  that instead of typing `00` a person can simply place `h` with a number but due to some error it is also matching decimal numbers, too.

Pattern that I wrote is `(\d+)(h|t|l)`

Comment: Do you mean you want to match the whole string? `^(\d+)(h|t|l)$`. Or, if you can have the number anywhere in the string, `(?<!\d)(?<!\d\.)(\d+)([htl])\b`. Depending on the regex flavor, `(?<!\d)(?<!\d\.)` can be written as `(?<!\d|\d\.)` or even `(?<!\d\.{0,1})`

Comment: i want a match  anywhere in the string

Comment: What is the regex flavor? `regexp-replace` tag implies you are using Oracle. Is it so?

Comment: i am using autohotkey not sure about the engine

Comment: It uses PCRE. Removing the tag. You may use `(?<!\d|\d\.)(\d+)([htl])\b`

Answer (score 2):

You could use a whitespace boundary to the left `(?<!\S)` if a positive lookbehind is supported or anchors to match the whole line.

The alternation can be written as a character class `[htl]`

```
(?<!\S)(\d+)([htl])
```

- `(?<!\S)` Positive lookbehind, assert what is on the left is not a non whitespace char
- `(\d+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ digits
- `([htl])` Capture group 2, match either `h` t`or`l`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dop4HU/1)

Using anchors to match the whole line

```
^(\d+)([htl])$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jUw3Jc/1)

Without a lookaround, you could match either a whitespace char or the start of the string `(?:\s|^)` for example:

```
(?:\s|^)(\d+)([htl])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zJw0DY/1)

Comment: ...or just `(?<!\S)\d+[htl]` if there is no need to capture the two components of the match separately.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Correct, I used the given pattern with groups as I don't know if the OP needs the groups for autohotkey.